# How can I use Linux command 'cd' when I have Greek language pack?

Tags: linux, command-line, command-prompt, cd

Sometimes I encounter this problem. In Greek, desktop is called 'Επιφάνεια εργασίας'. I can switch to Greek on the terminal, but I can't use intonation, or however the mark above α is called. Is there any way to use ά instead of α? Thank you in advance.

Tip: the problem is that, to put intonation, you press first the ' key and then the letter. But when I do this, I get:    "Επιφ'ανεια εργασ'ιας".

Comment: **locale** return what charset ? (UTF-8 should fix your problem)

Comment: this is a keyboard layout issue, are you using a layout without dead keys? If so, change it.

Comment: I can put intonation when typing in a .odt for example, but I encounter this only in the command line